# LINQ - Combine multiple lists to form a new list and align them by key?

Tags: linq, list, linq-to-objects

I have two list of different columns, but each list have a common column with the same key, how do I combine them into a new list, i.e:

```
public class TradeBalanceBreak
{
    public int CommID { get; set; }
    public int CPFirmID { get; set; }
    public double CreditDfferenceNotional { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Commission
{
    public int CommID { get; set; }
    public PeriodStart { get; set; }
    public ResearchCredit { get; set; }
}

public class CommissionList
{
    public List<Commission> Commissions { get { return GetCommissions(); }}

    private List<Commission> GetCommissions()
    {
        // retrieve data code ... ...
    }
}

public class TradeBalanceBreakModel
{
    public List<TradeBalanceBreak> TradeBalanceBreaks { get; set; }
}

public class CommissionModel
{
    public List<CommissionList> CommissionLists { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to combine/flatten the `TradeBalancesBreaks` and `CommissionLists` (from the model classes) into one. The `CommID` is shared between the two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Join (extension method version) -- after your update

```
 var list1 = GetTradeBalanceBreaks();
 var list2 = new CommisionsList().Commissions;

 var combined = list1.Join( list2,  l1 => l1.ID, l2 => l2.First().ID,
                            (l1,l2) = > new
                                        {
                                           l1.CommID, 
                                           l1.CPFirmID,
                                           l1.CreditDifferenceNotional,
                                           l1.Currency,
                                           PeriodStarts= l2.SelectMany( l => l.PeriodStart ),
                                           ResearchCredits = l2.SelectMany( l => l.ResearchCredit ) 
                                       })
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I've just updated my original question, as `List 2` is actually a List of List, a bit more complicated. Would you please take a look? Thank you.

Comment: @Saxman - you can get close, but not exactly what you want.  The problem is that you have an indeterminate number of address/fax pairs for each one, but the selection must have the same set of parameters.  If you'd be willing to tolerate a list of addresses and a list of fax numbers as the property, it would work.  See my update.

Comment: I got this error when trying your updated code, basically on where you showed the `Addresses = l2.SelectMany...`. First, I need to drill down a bit deeper, I can't just do `l2.SelectMany(...)`, I need to do something like `l2.Addresses.SelectMany(....)`, then this is the error returned: `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` Thanks for looking.

Comment: @Saxman -- headed home right now, but if you could update with the exact types of your list it would help.  Leave a comment for me here and I'll see what I can do based on your new information.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I've updated my original question with the models/classes that I'm working with. Would you take a look? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Saxman - I've updated my example with your new class information.

Answer (score 4):

```
var combined = from p in PhoneNumbers
               join a in Addresses on a.ID equals p.ID
               select new {
                   ID = p.ID,
                   Name = p.Name,
                   Phone = p.Phone,
                   Address = a.Address,
                   Fax = a.Fax
               };
```

Comment: I've just updated my original question, as `List 2` is actually a List of List, a bit more complicated. Would you please take a look? Thank you.